# How to programatically enable and execute task in .targets file for Project

Tags: delphi, msbuild, c++builder

I have custom .targets file (which is MSBuild file as RAD Studio support them since 2009) in my (Delphi) Project.

The **.targets** file is working fine - I added it to my project using [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Targets_Files) article.
When I right-click it and select Enable, then Targets->Compile the associated task inside it is executed and everything works fine.

[image: .targets file right click menu]

The question is how to automate this. I want to execute this task (e.g. Build) every time the Project is built (Compile or Build action: F9 or Ctrl+F9 in IDE).

I am able to access the IOTAProject in AfterCompile() method from where I can also get the .targets file as IOTAModuleInfo, but I found no way how to access the .targets right-click menu.

```
  TIDENotifierTemplate = Class(TNotifierObject, IOTANotifier, IOTAIDENotifier50, IOTAIDENotifier80, IOTAIDENotifier)
  Public
    // IOTANotifier
    Procedure AfterSave;
    Procedure BeforeSave;
    Procedure Destroyed;
    Procedure Modified;
    // IOTAIDENotifier
    Procedure FileNotification(NotifyCode: TOTAFileNotification; Const FileName: String; Var Cancel: Boolean);
    Procedure BeforeCompile(Const Project: IOTAProject; Var Cancel: Boolean); Overload;
    Procedure AfterCompile(Succeeded: Boolean); Overload;
    // IOTAIDENotifier50
    Procedure BeforeCompile(Const Project: IOTAProject; IsCodeInsight: Boolean; Var Cancel: Boolean); Overload;
    Procedure AfterCompile(Succeeded: Boolean; IsCodeInsight: Boolean);  Overload;
    Procedure AfterCompile(Const Project: IOTAProject; Succeeded: Boolean; IsCodeInsight: Boolean); Overload;
  End;
```

Can I achieve this with Open Tools API or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to perform it as a pre-build or post-build action. You'll have to script it up with a call to msbuild, but that is simple enough.